# URL country code prefixes and Internationalizing Pyramid web app

Tags: internationalization, translation, pyramid

I am working on the internationalization of my Pyramid web app, and wanted to **get advice** on how to set **URL country code prefixes** as suggested at http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/internationalization-and-localization.html#search-engine-considerations

I currently have implemented internationalization thanks to http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/templates/mako_i18n.html recipe and http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html, but I would love to find best practices for setting up country code URL prefixes depending on the locale.

Answer (score 0):

The officially supported documentation for Pyramid is your best source of information. See [Internationalization and Localization](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/i18n.html).

Neither of the links you provided are officially supported by Pyramid.  The first is for the Pylons web framework from 2009, and the latter is a community contributed cookbook recipe from 2011.

Comment: Thanks, I have been reading it and using it as resource, though there is nothing related to the question in the article as I understand it. I will edit my question to quote this resource.

Comment: It's not an article. It's documentation of internationalization and localization in Pyramid. Translations and localizations are handled in view code, as many of the examples in that page of the documentation indicate. Sorry for the convenience. You should also configure a default locale when the user's intent is ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, as per the title, I do not have problem with translation nor localization, my question is on how to set up URL country code prefixes dynamically according to the locale used.

Comment: Perhaps give a concrete example of what you mean by "dynamically"? Do you mean something like these, where the country code is part of the URL?

http://example.com/es/page

http://example.com/en/page

Comment: Yes, exactly. A specific locale, would lead to reroute request from example.com/page to example.com/<locale>/page

Comment: Oh, do you mean an [HTTPRedirection](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/httpexceptions.html#pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPRedirection) (what you call a reroute)? If so, you need to do a couple of things. (1) [Do an HTTPRedirect to handle the URL without the locale specified](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html#http-redirect). (2) Set up a default locale (see previous link to the docs).

Comment: Ok. Is there a good practice to redirect to a url with locale as a prefix (example.com/es/page, example.com/en/page)? (I honestly thought that it was clear from my question above 'but I would love to find best practices for setting up country code URL prefixes depending on the locale.')

Comment: Do you mean a good example other than those in the docs at the links I provided? I know of no others.